# omnipay eway module: InvoiceReference field

Tags: payment-gateway, omnipay

I am having trouble mapping the documentation from eway to the omnipay eway code.

Reading the eway documentation [Rapid 3.0 Transparent Redirect API](http://www.eway.com.au/docs/api-documentation/rapid3-0documentation.pdf) (page 23) uses a field *InvoiceReference* 'The merchant’s reference number for this transaction'.  I want to use this as a UUID on my website. Then my response handler can match that UUID and confirm the payment.

The problem i have is matching the documentation from the eway API to the code in omnipay.

In eway/src/Message/RapidPurchaseRequest.php there is:

```
$data['Payment'] = array();
$data['Payment']['TotalAmount'] = $this->getAmountInteger();
$data['Payment']['InvoiceNumber'] = $this->getTransactionId();
$data['Payment']['InvoiceDescription'] = $this->getDescription();
$data['Payment']['CurrencyCode'] = $this->getCurrency();
```

but nothing about 'InvoiceReference'.  I understand the omnipay gateway has its own editorial rules for variable names, and if the documentation was not so sparse I could  probably work it out.

So, can i use the (eway) *InvoiceReference* (string:50)  attribute with omnipay? or has that just not been implemented in the eway module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update Feb 2015:** My pull request has been accepted and the [Invoice Reference](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-eway/blob/master/src/Message/RapidPurchaseRequest.php#L28) has been added to the OmniPay eWAY library.

---

You are correct - the field hasn't been implemented in the eWAY module yet, at the moment only the standard OmniPay fields that match eWAY fields have been implemented.

You could modify the `RapidPurchaseRequest` class to add the get/set functions and include the `InvoiceReference` field with the other `Payment` variables.

Or, it you prefer not to modify the OmniPay module, you can alter the data in your code before it gets sent:

```php
$data = $request->getData();
$data['Payment']['InvoiceReference'] = 'INV-0001';
$response = $request->sendData($data);
```

If you are after a unique ID, the response to this request comes with the `AccessCode` variable, which is documented as "A unique access code that is used to identify this transaction". This is also the code you can use to get the transaction results.

Comment: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/omnipay/eway/pull/5) with the additional fields for eWAY. [My fork](https://github.com/incarnate/eway) also has them until the pull is accepted.